# ubuntu 20.04 in vagrant open port to private network

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, ubuntu-20.04

Running 2VMs by Vagrant within the private network like:

- host1: 192.168.1.1/24
- host2: 192.168.1.2/24

In host1, the app listens port 6443. But cannot access in host2:

```sh
# host1
root@host1:~# ss -lntp | grep 6443
LISTEN    0         4096                     *:6443                   *:*        users:(("kube-apiserver",pid=10537,fd=7))

# host2
root@host2:~# nc -zv -w 3 192.168.1.2 6443
nc: connect to 192.168.1.2 port 6443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

(Actually, the app is the "kube-apiserver" and fail to join the host2 as a worker node with kubeadm)

What am I missed?

Both are ubuntu focal (box_version '20220215.1.0') and ufw are inactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change the IP of hosts, it works:

- host1: 192.168.1.1/24 -> **192.168.1.2/24**
- host2: 192.168.1.2/24 -> **192.168.1.3/24**

I guess it is caused by **using the reserved IP as the gateway**, the first IP of the subnet, 192.168.1.1.

I'll update the references about that here later, I have to setup the k8s cluster for now.